# Complex queries with MongoTemplate and Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am using plain mongodb api i.e. MongoClient, DB, DBCollection, AggregrationOutput and DBObejct etc. I have following query which is working fine:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("myDB");
DBCollection    collection = db.getCollection("my_data");
List<DBObject> pipeline=new ArrayList<DBObject>();              
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("date", sdf.format(new Date())).append("myName", myName));
DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$myDetails");
DBObject match2 = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("myDetails.type", "health"));
DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("myDetails.datetime", -1));
DBObject limit = new BasicDBObject("$limit", 1);

pipeline.add(match);
pipeline.add(unwind);
pipeline.add(match2);
pipeline.add(sort);
pipeline.add(limit);

AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Now, i want to move on to SpringData mongoDb api.
Can anybody help me writing the same query with MongoTemplate and MongoOperations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer, which i got from MongoOperations aggregation function:

```
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MongoConfig.class);
    MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate"); 

    AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("country").is("India"));
    AggregationOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("myDetails");
    AggregationOperation match2 = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("myDetails.type").is("health"));
    AggregationOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "myDetails.datetime");
    AggregationOperation limit = Aggregation.limit(1);

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, unwind, match2, sort, limit);
    System.out.println("Aggregation = "+aggregation);
    AggregationResults<AggregateFactoryResult> output = mongoOperation.aggregate(aggregation, "gui_data", AggregateFactoryResult.class);
    System.out.println("output = "+output.getMappedResults());
```